# Assigning commands to Procedure variable type in ATEasy environment

Tags: function-pointers, basic, ateasy

I am coding in the `ATEasy` environment which is BASIC programming.

Assume I have a variable of `Procedure` type, named `pFunc`.

And also I have DRV that has the command: `MYDRV EXECUTE MYCMD(iCnt,dResult)`.

The function that I want to use "sits" in another driver and it is not public.
So I only have access to the `COMMAND` that calls this function.

How do I assign the command to the Procedure variable?

I tried doing this:

```
pFunc =  MYDRV EXECUTE MYCMD
```

But it does not compile. It thinks I want to call the MYCMD commands and asks for parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got an answer from ATEasy support forum in Marvin Test Solution site:

https://www.marvintest.com/forums/Thread.aspx?ID=392#bottom

Apparently it is an issue that was fixed in ATEasy 8.

So this:

```
pFunc =  MYDRV EXECUTE MYCMD
```

actually works in ATEasy 8 and above